# How to redirect page from HTTP to HTTPS(IIS and Code methods)?

Tags: asp.net, http, redirect, iis-7, https

I was searching on web for this solutions and found so many solutions. Some of you might merge this with other question as duplicate(i dont mind), but there are some general questions i have as newbee which help me to understand this process and also other can use this. So my website works on both http(80) and https(443). I want my login and edit profile page to always redirect to HTTPS. I dont care about other pages.i binded the SSL and works fine with http and HTTPS.My application is in ASP.net and  server is Windows server 2008 with IIS7

So there are two ways i found through which you can do this. 1) Through IIS and 2) Through Code (Other methods are welcome)

My first question is which option is more feasible or optimal? I saw some of the comments with IIS and MS URL redirect module says they have problem redirection in some IE. And for code based solutions i am wondering is this the best method you can use.

I saw some commets which says if you have dynamic URL then IIS method might give you error for some URL with data.

Second is pros and cons of these two methods? So other can use one of those method according their needs

here are some of the answer i got from web

http://raoulpop.com/2007/08/07/automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https/

This is IIS method
http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

and i can go on with these solutions. But what i am asking is which is better way, ISS or code? You are welcome to post your ideas and your solutions which help me and other to understand this problem better.

Thanks in advance.
Arpan.